# Visibility of Form Components when Enabled is false C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visible

I have a form with labels and other components, picture boxes, panels, etc.. When I am doing `Form.enabled = false;` (because I have another form on top of it) the labels are not showing even though the visibility of the components is set to true; Any ideas?

I didn't include code because I'm not sure what to include!

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**: After what Joel Etherton said, I tried using this event:

```
private void label1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      label1.Visible = true;
}
```

This is giving me a `StackOverflowException`.. maybe this is infinitely trying to override the parent control visibility.. What can I do please?

Answer (score 1):

Check the element's parent objects (and follow it up the tree). Usually this is caused by a parent being set to `Visible = false;`. Visibility settings for a particular control will still register as `true`, but when the page is actually rendered it will stop producing controls at any parent level whose visibility is false.

*Edit:*
First you should find the root cause of the problem. This isn't a code issue so much as an expectation issue. A control is expected to be visible, but you've created a condition where that is not possible. I think you'd be better served by trying to find out what condition is causing a parent control to have a false visibility. Most likely you'll find either there is a logical problem with forcing a parent's visibility or a design problem where your "visible" control is being placed in the wrong root container. However, if you just want to brute force the visibility of parents you can have a recursive method do it:

```
private static void SetAllParentVisibility(bool visible, Control ctrl)
{
    ctrl.Visible = visible;
    if (ctrl.Parent != null)
        SetAllParentVisibility(visible, ctrl.Parent);
}
```

Also, treat the above method as psuedo-code. I haven't tested it out, and the type `Control` may need to be altered to be able to adjust to different parent types.

Comment: hmm thanks for your answer.. maybe I can use OnParentVisibilityChanged event?

Comment: Possible, but that would only register the immediate parent. If this problem is coming from a parent 3 levels up it'll never register. Keep in mind, the parent does not actually change the visibility of the children, so being as far away as a grandparent would make that event unusable.

Comment: so what do you suggest I do to make them visible then? Sorry, I'm literally stuck here :/

Comment: I found what the problem was.. Although have no idea why.. When I change the background colour of my form to black and the labels to white (from the palette), the labels don't show.. however when  have another background colour they show ok ! How does this have to do?!

Comment: Oh apparently while the form is not enabled the color of the labels is changing to navy blue, that's why they're not showing on black but showing on another color! But I'm never changing the color of the labels except setting the property fore-color to white :/